# 19.04 XPS Sometimes can't have wifi after wake from sleep

Tags: wireless, suspend

Sometimes upon wake from sleep it's in this bizarre zombie state where it's in airplane mode and no wifi available at all. Disable airplane mode, and bluetooth turns on. Turn off bluetooth, and airplane mode is activated. I've found that I can put it to sleep and wake it back up, it does a normal wakeup, wifi is available to the system, and it automatically reconnects to wifi like normal.

Comment: what are we supposed to do with that little information? XPS is too broad.

Comment: It probably has nothing to do with my particular hardware. This particular hardware didn't do this in prior Ubuntu versions, and it doesn't do it in Windows. Now, in 19.04, ONLY SOMETIMES, it fails to have wifi available at all after wake from sleep.

Comment: I have seen this with dell precision 7540 (however I can't even get it to go to sleep most of the time, but if it does, it behaves badly)